# Бот для решения теста

Tags: python, c++, бот

Задача простая. Есть много несложных тестов(1 из 4, выбрать несколько, соотнести). Они все расположены на одном сайте. После ответа на вопрос сразу же показывается правильный ответ (Не сама кнопка, а текст, что был на ней). Я хочу автоматизировать процесс и написать бота, который бы прорешивал тест 2 раза(один - для получения ответов, второй - решение). Просто я не имел опыта написания ботов, работаю на С++, изучаю Python. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я могу найти материал для решения данной задачи.

Comment: использовать  `selenium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Selenium

[docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) | [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) | [habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/250921/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://example.com/") # open a url

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q") # finds element by name ;)
elem.send_keys("Hello world!") # type something
elem.click() # click elemnt
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # or press a key
driver.close()
```

Поддерживаются языки: *[python](/questions/tagged/python)*, [java](/questions/tagged/java), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) etc.